# asymptotic estimate of random walk involved hitting time and return time

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Consider a reversible random walk on (say) $\mathbb{Z}$, are there any estimate for the following probability $\mathbb{P}(\tau_n=m<\tau_0^+)$ where $\tau_n$ is the first hitting time at site n and $\tau_0^+$ is the first return time to the starting point 0.

The conductance decrease exponentially in distance, but the Simple random walk case can be already helpful for me, thanks.

Comment: I forget to mention that the asymptotic is in m for some fixed n (large).

Answer (score 0):

I know for a fact that when $0\leq a\leq b$, we have $\mathbb{P}_a[\tau_0 < \tau_b] = 1-\tfrac{a}{b}$. So my guess is that your probability is equivalent to $\tfrac{1}{m}$ as $m\to+\infty$.